# Empty set - Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question might be very obvious but is the empty set a member of all subsets of a given set ?

I.e. $\big\{1,2,\left\{3,4\right\}\!\big\}\,,\,$ is $\,\emptyset\in\left\{3,4\right\}$ ?

Comment: $\phi \neq \{\phi \}$

Comment: No, the empty set is a set with no elements. The set $\left\{3,4\right\}$ does not have the element $\left\{\right\}$ in it.

Comment: No. The only things contained in the set are the things listed in the brackets. but the empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: I think you meant $\phi\subset \{3,4\}$, in which case it is correct.

Comment: No, the empty set is a *member* only if is an element that is specifically put there in the set.  The empty set is a *subset* of all sets.  But subsets are a *very* different thing than being a member.  If the set is $\{3, 4, \emptyset, 7, babar, chocolate\}$ then we can see that $\emptyset$ is one of the things in the set so $\emptyset \in \{3, 4, \emptyset, 7, babar, chocolate\}$ just like $7\in \{3, 4, \emptyset, 7, babar, chocolate\}$ or $chocolate\in\{3, 4, \emptyset, 7, babar, chocolate\}$. But if the set is $\{3,4\}$ then $\emptyset$ is not in there so $\emptyset \not \in \{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be something you misheard which you are Posting here.

**(1) The Empty Set is a subset of every Set.**
In your Case , $X=\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$ , we have a Set with 3 (not 4) elements.
The "last element" is itself a Set with 2 elements.

Is $∅ ∈ \{3,4\}$ : NO.
Is $∅ \subset \{3,4\}$ : YES.
Is $∅ ∈ X$ : NO.
Is $∅ \subset X$ : YES.

You may have misheard "subset of" like "member of".

NO : "the empty set is a **member** of all subsets of a given set"
YES : "the empty set is a **subset** of a given set"

**(2) The Empty Set is in the PowerSet of every Set.**
Power Set (of a given Set X) is made up of all subsets of X.
Here , ∅ is itself among the subsets of X , hence it will be among the elements of PowerSet of X , hence ∅ is a member of the PowerSet of a given Set X.

$P = PowerSet (X) = \{ \{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\{3,4\}\} , \{1,\{3,4\}\} , \{2,\{3,4\}\} , \{1,2,\{3,4\}\} \}$ , having $2^3=8$ elements.

Is $∅ ∈ P$ : YES.
Is $∅ \subset P$ : YES.
Is $∅ ∈ X$ : NO.
Is $∅ \subset X$ : YES.

Here, you may have misheard "PowerSet of every Set" like "every Set".

NO : "the empty set is a **member of all subsets** of a given set"
YES : "the empty set is a member of **the set of** all subsets of a given set"

Details are available in Set Theory textbooks or online material.

Comment: Why did you write that $\,\emptyset\in3$ ?

Comment: Is it correct to write that $\;0=\emptyset\;,\;1=\{0\}\;,\;2=\{0,1\}\;,\;3=\{0,1,2\}\;?$ If it is correct, then it is also correct that $\;\emptyset\in 3\;.$

Comment: Due to MATHJAX Issue , I think there was some confusion , @Angelo , I had missed some slashes which User Akiva added. Now , that confusion should not be there !

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set $A= \{3,4, apple, chocolate, \pi\}$ then the elements that are in the set are $3,4,apple, chocolate,$ and $\pi$.  Those are the elements of the set and nothing else is an element of the set.  As none of those are the $\emptyset$, $\emptyset$ is not an element of $A$ and $\emptyset \not \in A$.

If you have a set $B = \{92, 47, hike, \emptyset, alligator, kiss\}$ then the elements that are in the set are $92,47, hike, \emptyset, alligator, $ and $kiss$.  Those are the elements of the set and nothing else is an element of the sets.  As one of these elements is indeed $\emptyset$ (see it? there? right between $hike$ and $alligator$?) then $\emptyset$ is an element of $B$ so $\emptyset \in B$.

Some sets may have $\emptyset$ as a member.... and other sets won't.

.......

What you probably had heard was that $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of every set.  That is a *very* different statement.  A subset of a set $A$ is *not* an element of $A$.  A subset of $A$ is a *set* that consists of elements that are in $A$.

For example if $A = \{3,4, apple, chocolate, \pi\}$ then $\{3,chocolate\}$ is a subset of $A$ because all the elements of $A$ (which are $3$ and $chocolate$ are all elements that are in $A$.  But $\{3,chocolate\}$ is *not* an element of $A$ because of the five elements of $A$, (that is $3,4, apple, chocolate,$ and $ \pi$, none of them are the same thing as $\{3,4\}$).

Now the emptyset doesn't have any elements.  That means that all the elements that it has (which is zero) are in $A$ because the empty set doesn't have any elements that are *not* in $A$.... because the empty set doesn't have any elements at all... so it doesn't have any that *aren't* in $A$... so all the elements it does have (which is zero) are in $A$.

It might seem a bit like a nasty language word trick, but it *is* logical and it is consistant with math.

......

> $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of every set.  But $\emptyset$ is only a member of sets.... that have $\emptyset$ as a member.